# Normalizing spatial heatmap by population density

Tags: r, plot, visualization, gis

I have a bunch of lat/long points corresponding to where people with a certain accent feature grew up in the US, and I want to understand where geographically this tends to be.

I want to avoid the [XKCD population density heatmap trope](https://xkcd.com/1138/) and control/normalize for population density.  I.e., I don't want the fact that many people live in big cities (and are thus more likely to have responded to the survey) to skew my results, etc.

My goal is to plot this information as a gradient heatmap for qualitative findings--not to do significance testing or statistical test.  What's the best way to do this in R?

Answer (score 0):

One approach, as developed by Stan Openshaw and his GAM, is to draw a circle and calculate the sum of the incidents over the sum of the population (subset) that fall with in the circle. The apply a kernel smoothing over the circle. Repeat for many circles across your data area and for a range of radii.

Comment: Would it also work to just do a 2d gaussian kernel density estimate of the survey coordinates and then the same thing for population, and divide the density of the first by the latter?

Comment: Might do, but you're running the risk of artefacts creeping in

Comment: I'm not looking to actually do a cluster analysis or test significance, I'm just looking to correct the heatmap. What kind of artifacts are you envisioning?

Comment: Mismatches from rounding error and distance calculations - plus it will take twice as long as doing one kernel estimate